# Is it possible to do equivalent of SQL "HAVING" in elasticsearch aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm doing an an aggregation where I'm looking for term frequency of a certain field.  There are many terms that are very common, many of that are very uncommon and some of that are moderately common.  I would like to find those.

In SQL I would do something like `HAVING num_words < 300 and num_words >50`. I'm trying to find a way to tell the aggregation do the same thing.

How would I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you are searching for a [numeric range filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-numeric-range-filter.html)

Comment: This will be possible with ES 2.0 which will provide support for [post processing aggregation results](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110). I'm not aware of a way to do it with ES 1.x. You can always do this on the client-side, though.

Comment: @RedX - it seems that's only filtering at the doc level, not the aggregation level.  But please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Val  - I know, I can't wait

Comment: @Yehosef Yes, i did ot know your num_words was the result of an aggregration.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/indexName/typeName/_search' -d '
{
"min_score": 1,
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "boost_mode": "replace",
        "script_score": {
            "lang": "javascript",
            "script": "if(_score>min_value && _score<max_value) {_score} else {0.0}",
            "params": {
                "min_value": 0,
                "max_value": 1000
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "score_type": "sum",
            "query": {
                "function_score": {
                    "boost_mode": "replace",
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": "if(doc[\"indexname.amt\"]) {doc[\"indexname.amt\"].value} else {0.0}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

This is part of my request. I hope it could help you.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use this - it seems to be dealing with the score at the document level, not the aggregation level.  But maybe I'm missing something.  Can you explain more?

Comment: Yeah, request can count value and than this part of request ("script": "if(_score>min_value && _score<max_value) {_score} else {0.0}") explain what it would be show. Like a HAVING counted_value>100. You can add your own rule.

Comment: but where is the aggregation? The "query" clause runs on the raw documents, not on the aggregation.  It seems more like this is `WHERE counted_value>100` than `HAVING counted_value>100`

Comment: This example just show how to possible make post processing actions.